# How do I make a custom UIElement-derived class that contains (and displays) other UIElements as children?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, rendering, uielement

Let's say I want to make a class that inherits directly from `UIElement` and is able to contain one or more [externally added] `UIElement`s as children - like `Panel`s and other container controls. It's obviously easy to have the class house a collection of `UIElement`s in some form or other, but how do I get them to be displayed / rendered along with my class?

I assume they must be added to the visual tree as children of my own `UIElement` in some way (or, possibly, render them manually à la going via `VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing` and do it using `OnRender`'s `DrawingContext`? But that seems clumsy).

I do **not** want to know that I can - or should - inherit from more ready-made controls, like `FrameworkElement`, `Panel`, `ContentControl` etc (if anything, I want to know how **they** are implementing the displaying / rendering of externally added child elements, where applicable).

I have my reasons for wanting to be as high up in the hierarchy as possible, so please don't give me any lectures on why it is a good thing to be XAML / WPF Framework 'compliant' etc.

Comment: Inspect `PresentationFramework.dll` with Reflector or something.

Comment: Lol - I was *this* close to adding "you hear that, HighCore?" at the end of the last paragraph (before I noticed there was a comment.. but you beat me to it).

Comment: Don't remember if I said this to you, but yes, you're an experimented developer who really `knows` what he's doing, but for most people out there using WPF, it's quite the opposite. That's why I have this cliche of "delete all your code and learn MVVM" thing constantly coming up again and again. Of course that doesn't apply to you, and other pro WPF/XAML devs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following class provides the absolute minimum in terms of layout and rendering of child elements:

```
public class UIElementContainer : UIElement
{
    private readonly UIElementCollection children;

    public UIElementContainer()
    {
        children = new UIElementCollection(this, null);
    }

    public void AddChild(UIElement element)
    {
        children.Add(element);
    }

    public void RemoveChild(UIElement element)
    {
        children.Remove(element);
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return children.Count; }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return children[index];
    }

    protected override Size MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement element in children)
        {
            element.Measure(availableSize);
        }

        return new Size();
    }

    protected override void ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
    {
        foreach (UIElement element in children)
        {
            element.Arrange(finalRect);
        }
    }
}
```

It is not required to have a UIElementCollection. An alternative implementation could look like this:

```
public class UIElementContainer : UIElement
{
    private readonly List<UIElement> children = new List<UIElement>();

    public void AddChild(UIElement element)
    {
        children.Add(element);
        AddVisualChild(element);
    }

    public void RemoveChild(UIElement element)
    {
        if (children.Remove(element))
        {
            RemoveVisualChild(element);
        }
    }

    // plus the four overrides
}
```

Comment: No, you may as well use a plain list and call Add/RemoveVisualChild to set up the visual tree. The magic is in the four overrides.

Comment: Great, this is just what I was looking for (and regarding my previous comment: for a second, I thought maybe the handling of the children was embedded in UIElementCollection, since it gets initialized with `this` - I thought that could mean it did the hooking up with the visual tree etc). How much of this is really stemming from `Visual`?

Comment: All that has Visual in its name: Add/RemoveVisualChild, VisualChildrenCount and GetVisualChild. UIElement adds MeasureCore and ArrangeCore.

Comment: ..but inheriting from Visual is useless in practice, right? I read somewhere that its actual rendering mechanisms are `Internal` so they can only be accessed indirectly, via one of its descendants..?

Comment: Well, I've got a very practical use case where I derive from ContainerVisual and DrawingVisual. You may take a look at classes TileContainer and TileLayer in my [XAML Map Control](http://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.

Comment: Yes, going via DrawingVisual was what I was thinking of - looks like the best access point for building a set of bare-boned custom `Visual`s without the fluff from UIElement (not to mention FrameworkElement).

Comment: Hi, I got the same question for a FrameworkElement instead of an UIElement (as in Silverlight, UIElement's constructor is private). Can you help?

Comment: @Cœur Have you tried anything yourselves? If so, and you have any specific problem with your approach, ask a question here on StackOverflow.